# Proof that sum of subspaces gives $\mathbb{R}^{n}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let A be square matrix of order $n\geq2$ such that $A^{2}=I$. Prove
>   that $\mathbb{R}^{n}=U\oplus W$, where $U=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}:\;
>  Ax=x\},\; W=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}:\; Ax=-x\}$.

To prove, I need to show that $\mathbb{R}^{n}=U+W$ and $U\cap W=\{0\}$. The latter is easy: $U\cap W=\{0\}$ because $\begin{cases}Ax=x\\Ax=-x\end{cases}\Rightarrow x=-x\Rightarrow x=0$.

Please, help me with the proof of $\mathbb{R}^{n}=U+W$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that $$v=\frac{1}{2}(v+Av)+\frac{1}{2}(v-Av)$$ where $v \in \mathbb{R^n}$

Comment: I understood that $Av \in U, -Av \in W$, but I don't see that  $v+Av \in U, v-Av \in W$

Comment: $A(v+Av)=Av+v=1(v+Av)$ and $A(v-Av)=Av-v=-1(v-Av)$

Comment: I see now, thank you!